# categorical variables vs continuous variables

Tags: continuous-data, accuracy

When to Be Discrete: Continuous vs. Categorical Predictors. I want to know whether I should bring variables as categorical into the model or continuous? Which factor should I consider? When should I categorize one continuous variable? When shouldn't I? And How categorize a continuous variable?

Comment: There's an awful lot to discuss here.  Do you have a specific problem in mind that you could describe in order to focus your question into a more answerable range of topics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For confirmatory study, you should have no choice because the analysis plan should have clear description on how to deal with this situation.

Use linear model as example. For exploratory study, use continuous predictor $x$ first. Draw a scatterplot of residual vs. $x$ to check is there any patterns. If no patterns (the residual looks like the white noise), no need to categorize. Otherwise, try to add square, square root, and/or logarithm ... of $x$ and check the residual again. If patterns exist still, get ride of all of $x$ terms, and try to categorize the $x$. The scatterplot of residual (from the model without x related terms) vs. $x$ may provide some idea on how to group the $x$. Also the scientific meaning of grouping should play important role. For example, grouping age at 18, 50, 65 years has some physiological and/or sociological meaning.

In summary, categorizing the continue variable into categorical variable is not a good practice, and it would be last recourse.

Comment: @ a_statistician, thanks for the great advice. What is the difference between confirmatory and explanatory studies? and also what do you mean about the scatterplot of residual (from the model without x related terms)? It means the residuals of a model which does not include x and also its interaction with the other variables?

Comment: Confirmatory study has the protocol describing the detailed process. Generally analysis plan is part of the protocol. The researchers need to follow protocol strictly. The results are very reliable. Exploratory study has no protocol or has very general protocol. In the process of the study, the protocol (if any) can be changed very often. It is common there is no analysis plan. After data are available, you can try different statistical methods and pick up one you like.       As for scatterplot, yes the residuals come from the model without x and its interaction.

Comment: @ a_statistician, thanks so much for your great advice.

Answer (score 0):

Depends. What are your objectives in modeling? What do you want to be able to do with your model? I don't exactly know what you mean by categorizing a continuous variable, but I am working on a project where I some of my models have continuous output, and others ternary (three classes). When I combine the models with weighting, I categorize my continuous output into the same three classes.

In terms of what the boundaries of the classes should be, you will have to figure that out yourself either by experimentally varying the boundaries or algorithmically, perhaps with cross-validation.